# Plugin Use Default Value When Empty

Tags: plugin-development, models, records

I've got a default value defined in my model for a field

```
'limit' => array(AttributeType::Number, 'default' => 0)
```

When I create a new record, if the limit field is empty, `NULL` gets stored in the DB instead of 0. I thought `$model->setAttributes()` would set the default values if the values coming in were `NULL`. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you define the default value for the attribute in your record as well?

Comment: Yes, it's on the record as well.

Comment: Does the `limit` column in the database have a default set?  Did the record create the table?

Comment: Ahhh nope because this column was added in a DB migration. How can I set the default value in a migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a default to an existing column in a table in a migration, you'd do something like this:

```
$this->alterColumn('tableName', 'columnName', array('column' => ColumnType::Number, 'default' => 0));
```

If you want to add a default to a new column in a table in a migration, you'd do something like this:

```
$this->addColumn('tableName', 'columnName', array('column' => ColumnType::Number, 'default' => 0));
```